# My workout routine and diet seem to be poorly matching my expectations - can anyone advice on how to improve it

Tags: diet, home-exercise, routine

I'm 19, male and I've started my routine more or less 2 years ago cuz I was ugly. I wanted to end up with a six pack and a nice waistline as well as get taller.

I never did any sports before on regular basis, hence I didn't know much - so I've just tossed together some online workout routines as a basis at the start, and then just increased the time and amount every some time.

last time I've changed the timing & amount was a year ago, because as i started studies at university I was not able to afford more then hour and a half daily for it, and usually it took me about 2 hours after I increased the timing for some time.

Currently I do following on daily basis in the respected order (I don't know names of most exercises so they have a description instead):

1. Lie on the back and elevate my upper body and left leg up until they connect, then revert to the original position and repeat. I do this one 40 times in one go, then 20 more after 10 seconds break.
2. Lie on the back and elevate my upper body and right leg up until they connect, then revert to the original position and repeat. I do this one 40 times in one go, then 20 more after 10 seconds break.
3. Lie on the back, arms stretched in parallel to the ground, and elevate both legs up until they are at right angle to the ground, then revert to original position and repeat. I do this 40 times in one go, then 20 more after 10 seconds break.
4. Lie on the back, arms held behind my head, and elevate upper body and both legs up, then revert to original position and repeat. I do this 40 times in one go, then 20 more after 10 seconds break.
5. Lie on the back, arms behind my head, elevate my upper body and move legs up and down in cross phase without letting them touch the ground. I do this for a minute and a half in one go, then 30 seconds more after 20 seconds break.
6. Lie on left side, left arm bend 90 degrees such that the end of the arm is in parallel with the ground, keep feet one on another and affixed together, elevate my body so the only points of contact with ground are my arm and feet. I do this 60 times.
7. Lie on right side, right  arm bend 90 degrees such that the end of the arm is in parallel with the ground, keep feet one on another and affixed together, elevate my body so the only points of contact with ground are my arm and feet. I do this 60 times.
8. Lie on the back, both legs are bent in the knees. I pull them to the chest and stretch back in cross phase. I do this for 2 minutes, then 30 seconds more after short 20 seconds break.

(here is take couple minute break)

9. 3 minute plank.
10. 30 push ups (i have problems keeping the count and breathing at the same time so it usually ends around 10 more, but 30 is the number i stick with because that's the minimum i know i never fall below).
11. Stand straight, legs spread around as wide as my shoulders, arms down holding dumbbells (9 kg each). bend my arm in the same plane as my body until the dumbbell is above my shoulder, then revert to original position. I do this for a total of 80 timer per arm, interchanging arms after 20 times, and having a break for 30 seconds after 60 per arm was done.
12. 30 more push ups.
13. Stand straight, legs spread around as wide as my shoulders, my arms are bend in elbow above my shoulders holding the dumbbells. Elevate dumbbells and revert them to their original position in cross phase. I do this 20 times per arm.
14. Put my body into a position which is observed at the start of the push up. Bring my knees up to my chest. I do this 80 times, changing legs every 20 times.

(here i take couple minutes break)

15. Stand straight, legs spread around as wide as my shoulders, my arms lie at rest on sides holding dumbbells. I raise arms at 90 degrees to my body keeping them straight, and hold dumbbells. I do this for 40 seconds in one go, and 30 seconds after 10 second break.
16. Stand straight, legs spread around as wide as my shoulders, arms down holding dumbbells (9 kg each). bend my arm in the same plane as my body until the dumbbell is above my shoulder, then revert to original position. I do this for a total of 40 timer per arm, interchanging arms after 20 times.
17. I do squats, 30 in one go, 20 more after 10 seconds break.
18. Stand with knees slightly bent and one feet around 20 cm in front of another one. Preform moves similar to boxing jabs while holding the dumbbells in both arms. I do this 30 times per arm. I do it in chunks of 20 per arm, and then chunks of 10.
19. I do 20 more squats.

So I was sticking to this routine, and well I don't think i actually skipped it even once.
I understand that it's less intensive then the proper gym workout, but I hoped it would help me at least to some extent.

I've started with height of 1.87 meters, and weight of 56 kg. My height didn't change. I got up to 64 kg, and got average looking biceps and some vague hint at abs. I definitely noticed change in the width of shoulders and neck, but I still didn't get clearly defined waistline either.

Through the course of those 2 years I've also tried to adjust my diet. Again I have very little knowledge about it, so I just went with whatever seems healthy. I restraint from consuming sodas frequently, and removed white bread, potatoes, and all grain product outside of rye bread, and buckwheat. I ensured that I drink half a liter of fermented dairy product daily (because i moved a lot it ranged from polish kefir to drinking yoghurts). I made sure only meat i consume in my diet is either chicken or turkey, and just the breast part. I ensured i frequently eat eggs, lettuce and green onions, apples, cheese and other dairy. I also try to eat straight after the workout, and restrain from drinking during any physical exercises.

Now an acquittance of mine told me after i asked for advice that what i did was largely stupid, as my routine despite being done daily still lacks the proper levels of workload comparing to gym visits, and lacks diversity. He also mentioned that workout cannot improve height in person of my age, since anyway height is mostly genetics. And he mentioned that my diet is horribly incomplete, but since he is not a dietologist he shouldn't be the one advising me on a new one. Finally he mentions that man, opposing to woman cant physically get super distinct waistline without going very try hard about it because apparently we have different bones and such.

So yeah' here I am asking for advice from people who are more experienced then me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now an acquittance of mine told me after i asked for advice that what i did was largely stupid, as my routine despite being done daily still lacks the proper levels of workload comparing to gym visits, and lacks diversity. He also mentioned that workout cannot improve height in person of my age, since anyway height is mostly genetics. And he mentioned that my diet is horribly incomplete, but since he is not a dietologist he shouldn't be the one advising me on a new one. Finally he mentions that man, opposing to woman cant physically get super distinct waistline without going very try hard about it because apparently we have different bones and such.

Your friend's opinion is pretty much perfect. You should listen to him, and there's really not a lot to add to that.

That said, let's delve a little deeper...

> I've started with height of 1.87 meters, and weight of 56 kg.

This is a BMI of 16. That is extremely underweight. If you were assessed for anorexia, you'd be categorised as on the border of moderate and severe anorexia. In this state, wanting to "get a six pack" is terrible goal, and imposing any dietary restriction is just completely reckless. Instead, you should have been aiming to gain weight, and even at your current weight of 64kg (BMI of 18.3), you should still be aiming to gain weight.

To do this, you need to do two things:

- Eat more, and without restrictions. Drink sodas, eat grain products of any type, eat potatoes, eat all kinds of meat.
- (Assuming you want the weight gained to be muscle) focus your training on resistance exercises targeting all major muscle groups, and using enough resistance that it is impossible for you to do any more than 20 reps. Abdominal exercises (sit-ups, etc) should make up no more than 10% of all the exercises you do.

Overall, I'd strongly recommend taking your friend's advice to see a dietician. Having a restrictive diet at your bodyweight is dangerous and it sounds like you could really use professional help in learning how to eat to maintain a healthy bodyweight.

Comment: Thank you for advice - while I'm not anorexic (i guess), i certainly know what i was taking medicine which has some of its side effects to be reducing weight or gaining weight (I have no clue how it can be both, but that what my GP said at the time). Could you elaborate what do you mean by 20 "reps"? as In what is this unit, time or attempts, or...?

Comment: Rep = repetition. So if you do 20 squats, then rest, then do 20 more squats, you have done two sets, and each set contained twenty repetitions.